# Why thread pool works slow?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the program to count all words in all .log files in given directory using N threads.
I wrote something like this.
ThreadPool.h

```
#ifndef THREAD_POOL_H
#define THREAD_POOL_H

#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <future> // I don't how to work with boost future
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


class ThreadPool
{
public:
    using Task = std::function<void()>; // Our task

    explicit ThreadPool(int num_threads)
    {
        start(num_threads);
    }

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        stop();
    }

    template<class T>
    auto enqueue(T task)->std::future<decltype(task())>
    {
        // packaged_task wraps any Callable target
        auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task()) ()>>(std::move(task));

        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock{ mutex_p };
            tasks_p.emplace([=] {
                (*wrapper)();
            });
        }

        event_p.notify_one();

        return wrapper->get_future();
    }

    /*void enqueue(Task task)
    {
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock { mutex_p };
            tasks_p.emplace(std::move(task));
            event_p.notify_one();
        }
    }*/

private:
    std::vector<boost::thread> threads_p; // num of threads
    std::queue<Task>           tasks_p;   // Tasks to make
    boost::condition_variable  event_p; 
    boost::mutex               mutex_p;

    bool                       isStop = false;

    void start(int num_threads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            // Add to the end our thread
            threads_p.emplace_back([=] {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Task to do
                    Task task;

                    {
                        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);

                        event_p.wait(lock, [=] { return isStop || !tasks_p.empty(); });

                        // If we make all tasks
                        if (isStop && tasks_p.empty())
                            break;

                        // Take new task from queue
                        task = std::move(tasks_p.front());
                        tasks_p.pop();
                    }

                    // Execute our task
                    task();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void stop() noexcept
    {
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_p);
            isStop = true;
        }

        event_p.notify_all();

        for (auto& thread : threads_p)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono> 

#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <locale.h>


namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

//int count_words(boost::filesystem::ifstream& file)
//{
//  int counter = 0;
//  std::string buffer;
//  while (file >> buffer)
//  {
//      ++counter;
//  }
//  
//  return counter;
//}
//
int count_words(boost::filesystem::path filename)
{
    boost::filesystem::ifstream ifs(filename);
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cin.tie(0);
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    bfs::path path = argv[1];
    // If this path is exist and if this is dir
    if (bfs::exists(path) && bfs::is_directory(path))
    {
        // Number of threads. Default = 4
        int n = (argc == 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 4);
        ThreadPool pool(n);

        // Container to store all filenames and number of words inside them
        //std::map<bfs::path, std::future<int>> all_files_and_sums;
        std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
        
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        // Iterate all files in dir
        for (auto& p : bfs::directory_iterator(path)) {
            // Takes only .txt files
            if (p.path().extension() == ".log") {
                // Future for taking value from here
                auto fut = pool.enqueue([p]() {
                    // In this lambda function I count all words in file and return this value
                    int result = count_words(p.path());
                    static int count = 0;
                    ++count;
                    std::ostringstream oss;
                    oss << count << ". TID, " << GetCurrentThreadId() << "\n";
                    std::cout << oss.str();
                    return result;
                });
                // "filename = words in this .txt file"
                futures.emplace_back(std::move(fut));
            }
        }

        int result = 0;

        for (auto& f : futures)
        {
            result += f.get();
        }

        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop - start);

        std::cout << "Result: " << result << "\n";
 
        std::cout << duration.count() << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::perror("Dir is not exist");
}
```

Variable N is 4(Number of threads). I've 320 .log files in my directory and I need count words in this files. Everything works fine but when variable "count" is 180 - the program stops for a while and then continues but much slower.
What could be the reason?
CPU - Xeon e5430 (I have tested this program on another CPU - the result is the same).

Comment: Your OS might be deprioritizing these threads because they are I/O bound.  Depending on the amount of data you're reading, it might even be the result of exhausting the disk cache and getting slower reads as a result.  Or it could even be a disk scheduling issue where your particular access pattern causes the OS to freak out.

Comment: Threads give you more cpu cycles, not disks.  Especially bad on spindle drives, they don't like to be jerked around.  Use only one thread to read.  There is no obvious way to gain more perf from processing the file data with threads if you only count words, unless you buffer a lot of data.  One extra thread is plenty good enough to keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you measure "slow" but basically you are using one of the worst models possible:

1. **one task queue** shared between all threads.

The problem with this approach is blocking in each thread on the shared queue.

A much better model is something like

2. **task stealing** - you can try creating a **task queue pro thread** and then use **try_lock** (which doesnt block) with enabling each thread "stealing" work from some other thread's tasks if it has nothing else to do.

This is very nice explained in excellent **[Sean Parent Talk about Concurrency](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#better-code-concurrency)**.